# Problema actualizando paquete python3.4 (3.4.2-1+deb8u3)

Tags: python, debian

Estaba actualizando un server con debian 8 y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Configurando python3.4 (3.4.2-1+deb8u3) ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1014
    raise InvalidURL(f"URL can't contain control characters. {url!r} "
                                                                     ^
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> dpkg: error al procesar el paquete python3.4 (--configure):
>        el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
>
> Se encontraron errores al procesar:
>
> ```
> python3.4
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
> ```

¿Alguna idea de que puede provocar el error?

Comment: Se me ocurre que pueda ser por el símbolo `!`

Comment: Parece que el mensaje que intenta generarse en el `raise` hace uso de "f-strings" (como puedes ver por la `f` que aparece delante de las comillas). Esta sintaxis es nueva y está sólo disponible a partir de Python 3.7. Es bastante raro que apparezca una cosa así al instlar python 3.4, parece que tengas una mezcla rara de versiones.

Comment: El problema es el comentado por abulafia, se intenta usar la sintaxis de los literales de cadena formateados (solo a partir de Python 3.6.x) en Python 3.4. Esa línea forma parte de un condicional introducido para corregir una vulnerabilidad ([CVE-2019-9740](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-9740)).

Comment: Python 3.4 no tiene soporte oficial  actualmente, pero creo que los responsables del paquete en Debian han metido la pata al intentar corregir la vulnerabilidad usando el mismo código del paquete oficial que es para Python >= 3.6...El bug está ya reportado:https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=931044

Comment: Deben haber copiado el módulo `http` de python 3.6 que no funciona en 3.4. En cambio el de python 3.5 casi seguro que funciona.

Answer (score 2):

por ahora existen dos soluciones. la primera es descargar la version de python que tiene el fix en Debian (python 3.4.2-1+deb8u4). tu problema debe suceder si tienes la version 3.4.2-1+deb8u3.

Si no puedes actualizar la version de python por algún motivo, La segunda solución es un poco mas rudimentaria pero muy fácil de hacer:

- primero abres el siguiente archivo: /usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py
- luego buscas la siguientes lineas

```
raise InvalidURL(f"URL can't contain control characters. {url!r} "                          
                 f"(found at least {match.group()!r})")
```

- y las remplazas con el siguiente código

```
raise InvalidURL("URL can't contain control characters. {url!r} "
                 "(found at least {group!r})"
                 .format(url=url, group=match.group()))
```

Esto ya resolverá tu problema.